# Extract lines from text file for the corresponding list of words?

Tags: python, text-mining

I am new to Python  and I am struggling with text mining issue.I am providing the problem statement below.

I have a PDF file and a list of words. I need to pick those lines from the file which contains any of the words in the mentioned list.

What I'm trying to do is : I am first converting the pdf file into text file and then I'm searching line by line, but I don't know how to search for more than one word and the second issue is I'm not able to pick full exact line.

Say, I have three words in lists: 'Commentary', 'Fund', and 'Country'.

Text File:

```
Country Of Registrations and Fund Charges

For details on fund charges and country of registrations please

see the KIID. For the Manager's investment commentary,

portfolio activity and market outlook, please see the Fund's

Profile at www.BlackRock.com.
```

So for word Commentary, it should pick below line

```
For the Manager's investment commentary,portfolio activity and market outlook, please see the Fund's Profile at www.BlackRock.com.
```

But it is picking: `see the KIID. For the Manager's investment commentary`

Can someone first help me to align the text in the file in proper format where one line should be the exact full sentence.

Comment: You need to parse sentences, which is actually not a trivial task.

Comment: As mentioned you need to parse sentences. You can join the lines back together then split(". ") to generate sentences but will miss all other punctuation and must have a space following a period. It will take a lot of work.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, you will have to parse sentences keeping different types of sentences in mind. Providing what methods you have tried may help others in answering question if you want help specifically !!